# how to customized sorting in an enum class in kotlin

Tags: sorting, enums, kotlin

I do have a enum class in kotlin in which I have to sort them differently based on a input parameters.

As of now, I have this class defined

```
enum class ProductItem constructor(
    val color,
    val price,
    val position
){

SHOES("red", "$", 2)
CAR("blue", "$$$$$", 1)
BOAT("green", "$$$$$$$$$$$$$", 3)
}
```

As of now using a simplify code like this:

```
it.sortedBy { it.ProductItem?.position })
```

I was expecting that the list of enum returned will be sorted in ascending order and show: `CAR, SHOES and BOAT` but it still shows `SHOES, CAR, BOAT`. It looks like the params `position` is not took into account. Any idea how to use the params position to sort the list of enum

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more please? What should be the logic for different sorting based on different parameter values (e.g. `State = CA` vs `State = LO`)?  And how do these state values relate to the enum values?

Comment: Hi @YoniGibbs I have update the description to a much simpler problem

Comment: I'm not sure what `it.ProductItem?.position` does... Is ProductItem here a property? Can you please provide a main function that demonstrates the problem. (Also your enum code does not compile.)

Answer (score 2):

From the look of your code I suspect you have some class (e.g. `Order`) which has an optional property called `ProductItem`, which returns a `ProductItem` enum value.  And you then have a list or array of these `Order` objects, which you want to sort by the `position` of the associated `ProductItem`.  Is that correct?

If so, here's some code below which shows how the list of orders can be sorted...

```
enum class ProductItem constructor(
        val color: String,
        val price: String,
        val position: Int
) {
    SHOES("red", "$", 2),
    CAR("blue", "$$$$$", 1),
    BOAT("green", "$$$$$$$$$$$$$", 3)
}

data class Order(val ProductItem: ProductItem? = null)

val orders = listOf(Order(ProductItem.SHOES), Order(ProductItem.CAR), Order(ProductItem.BOAT))
val sortedOrders = orders.sortedBy { it.ProductItem?.position }
```

Does that give you what you want?